# How can i acces my tomcat server in Android device via Wi-Fi?

Tags: android, performance, tomcat

Using a tomcat with `OpenVPN` on `localhost` to acces the `webserver`.

url: http://192.168.X.X:8080/test

It's working fine on browsers,

but it's not working on Android. Just the title and the page background is loading on Android browsers.

is Android support Apache Tomcat?

(The site build in AngularJS)